# py.warning: Just one line, but stacktrace needed for debugging

Tags: python, django, logging, python-imaging-library

I see this warning in my logs:

> py.warnings._decompression_bomb_check +2261: WARNING  [1091] /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:2261: DecompressionBombWarning: Image size (139332960 pixels) exceeds limit of 89478485 pixels, could be decompression bomb DOS attack.

Unfortunately this line alone does not help me to debug this.

I would like to see the stacktrace and other data like the request-URL.

We use Django 1.8 and Python 2.7

Above warning happens on a production system. About once a week.

I have no clue how to reproduce it, since I don't know the URL which produces the warning.

## Update

The warning is clear. But I have no clue where the huge image is stored. I am searching the file name of the huge file or the URL which produces this warning.

I think the only way to find is this: Add some debugging lines to the production environment and wait some days until the warning gets produced again.

Comment: What do you expect, the warning is almost clear?

Comment: The warning is clear. Yes, you are right. My problem: Which URL access the data? I want to debug this to find the huge image. The file path in the warning is a path to the python file. My question: Which URL does produce this error. I updated the question to make this more clear.

Comment: Further possibility: If the log entry has a time stamp, match the time stamp with the connection log to get the URL.

Comment: @stovfl yes, this type of guessing could help ... "ambiguity" I don't recall what Zen of Python said. Do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proposal to logging the filename**:

Copy the /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py
Open this file and edit the following:

```
def _open_core(fp, filename, prefix):
    # ...
    _decompression_bomb_check(im.size)
```

change to:

```
    _decompression_bomb_check(im.size, filename)
```

and the following:

```
def _decompression_bomb_check(size):
    # ...

    if pixels > MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS:
        warnings.warn(
```

to:

```
def _decompression_bomb_check(size, filename):
    # ...

    if pixels > MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS:
        warnings.warn(
            "Filename: %s"
            "Image size (%d pixels) exceeds limit of %d pixels, "
            "could be decompression bomb DOS attack." %
            (filename, pixels, MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS),
            DecompressionBombWarning)
```

Search the Internet to find a **sample DecompressionBomb Image**.
**Testing** your edits to `Image.py` with this sample.
If the logging met your needs, **backup the Original Image.py** and replace it with the editet one.
Then test your production system also.

Comment: OK, this works. I would like to avoid changing the upstream source code on production servers. But this answer definitely solves the issue. Thank you.

Comment: @aryamccarthy I used the checkmark at the left, since I found no checkmark at the right :-) .. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this sustainably in my opinion is to use [django-debug-toolbar](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). It gives you very detailed logs, request details, SQLs fired and what not on every URL of your app. The installation process is [pretty trivial](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) as well. Take it for a spin and see if you like it!

If you do however *absolutely need* to do it manually, I'd suggest defining your own middleware to do it. Something like

```
class CustomErrorHandlingMiddleware(self):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        # Handle exceptions here
        # Log to file or console as necessary
        return HttpResponse(...)
```

From the Django documentation,

> Django calls process_exception() when a view raises an exception. process_exception() should return either None or an HttpResponse object. If it returns an HttpResponse object, the template response and response middleware will be applied and the resulting response returned to the browser. Otherwise, default exception handling kicks in.

Comment: Sorry, my question was missing something. I updated the question "Above warning happens on a production system and I have no clue how to reproduce it, since I don't know the URL which produces the warning." This means django-debug-toolbar (which is a great tool) does  not help here.